# Translating/Scaling UIImageViews based on Screen Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a blank rectangular `uiview` that dynamically resizes based on the device screen size.

Into the `uiview`, I programmatically insert `uiimageview` `subviews` that I then save `CGRect`, `CGPoint`, and `CGAffineTransform` data to my database.

I can then fetch this data and re-upload and view the `uiimageview`s I had inserted previously.

All is well if I have the same device screen size, but my issue is trying to adapt these saved data points to other screen sizes so it optically looks good no matter what `iOS` device you may be on.

I tried storing alongside the other data points, the original height and width of the screen so I can, for example, find the change in width from the original to adjust the original x-coordinate to move more or less points.

```
let widthPointChange = new.bounds.width - saved.originalSuperviewWidth
let heightPointChange = new.bounds.height - saved.originalSuperviewHeight
 newUIImageView.center = CGPoint(x: saved.x + widthPointChange, y: saved.y + heightPointChange)
```

Is there a better way to do or think about this in terms translating/scaling according to various screen sizes but that stays true to the original? I'm wondering how, for example, Instagram is able to save user generated stories and display them consistently and proportionately across device sizes..

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach!

```
let view = UIView()
let image = UIImageView()

image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

view.addSubview(image)
```